# i have login screen problem home() this type of error

Tags: flutter

lib/LogInScreen.dart:54:76: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen()));
^
lib/HomeScreen.dart:10:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
HomeScreen(this.currenEmail);
^^^^^^^^^^
lib/LogInScreen.dart:212:76: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen()));
^
lib/HomeScreen.dart:10:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
HomeScreen(this.currenEmail);
^^^^^^^^^^
lib/LogInScreen.dart:247:74: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen()));
^
lib/HomeScreen.dart:10:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
HomeScreen(this.currenEmail);
^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: please provide more information about your issue, like the code that causes the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not pass the **currentEmail** when calling **HomeScreen**

```
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen(currentEmail)));
```

Your question is not clear.